# Spring file upload with multipart resolver causes connection reset when file is bigger than the limit

Tags: spring, file-upload, multipart

I try to allow users to upload some files with a size limitation. To do so, I use a multipart resolver :

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" 
        class="package.handlers.CustomizedMultipartResolver">
    <!-- max upload size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="4194304" /> <!-- 4MB -->

    <!-- max size of file in memory (in bytes) -->
    <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="4194304" /> <!-- 4MB -->

</bean>
```

Here my customized multipart resolver :

```
public class CustomizedMultipartResolver extends CommonsMultipartResolver {
/**
 * Parse the given servlet request, resolving its multipart elements.
 *
 * @param request the request to parse
 * @return the parsing result
 */
    @Override
    protected MultipartParsingResult parseRequest(final HttpServletRequest request) {
        String encoding = determineEncoding(request);
        FileUpload fileUpload = prepareFileUpload(encoding);

        List fileItems;

        try {
            System.out.println("ok");
            fileItems = ((ServletFileUpload) fileUpload).parseRequest(request);
        } catch (FileUploadBase.SizeLimitExceededException ex) {
            System.out.println("ok1");
            fileItems = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
        } catch (FileUploadException ex) {
            System.out.println("ok2");
            throw new MultipartException("Could not parse multipart servlet request", ex);
        }

        return parseFileItems(fileItems, encoding);
    }
}
```

My form :

```
<form:form action='<%= request.getContextPath().concat("/test") %>' commandName="FORM" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <form:input type="file" path="file"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form:form>
```

And the code that is in the controller :

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
public String processAdmin (@ModelAttribute(value="FORM") UploadForm form,BindingResult result) throws IOException {
    if(!result.hasErrors()){
        Files.write(Paths.get(System.getProperty("UPLOADER_HOME") + "/pub_marketing" + form.getFile().getOriginalFilename().substring(form.getFile().getOriginalFilename().lastIndexOf("."))), form.getFile().getBytes());

        return "redirect:" + myPage;
    }else{
        return "upload";
    }
}
```

So the problem is that when I try to upload a file with a size bigger than the limit, I get a connection reset and this trace :

```
ok
ok1
ok
ok1
juil. 23, 2015 6:26:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/index] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at package.controller.MyController.processAdmin(MyController.java:234)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

ok
ok1
juil. 23, 2015 6:26:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/index] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at package.controller.MyController.processAdmin(MyController.java:234)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

ok
ok1
```

Thanks for your help  :) (and sorry if there's any english mistake)

Comment: Why do you need the custom resolver at all? What does it add?

Comment: I tried lots of solutions to catch this error without getting a connection reset, this is the last in date. I found this solution with some searchs and thought that emptying the list would help me to detect the problem without causing an error.

Comment: When there is a failure you get an exception that should bubble up to the client. You are catching it and creating an empty list but in the controller you are assuming that there always is a file, add a null check. But I still don't see why you would need a custom resolver as you should simply get an exception.

Comment: Because for an unknown reason, even if I try to catch the exception it always ends with a connection reset. So I tried alternative ways.

Comment: And another problem is that I didn't even enter in the "/test" mapping

Comment: Well if there is an exception it will of course never reach the method...

Comment: Sure, but you wrote about a null check so I preferred to specify

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally have a solution !

The problem was not linked with Spring but with Tomcat and its connector's parameter "maxSwallowSize".

Tomcat's explanations for this parameter :
"The maximum number of request body bytes (excluding transfer encoding overhead) that will be swallowed by Tomcat for an aborted upload. An aborted upload is when Tomcat knows that the request body is going to be ignored but the client still sends it. If Tomcat does not swallow the body the client is unlikely to see the response. If not specified the default of 2097152 (2 megabytes) will be used. A value of less than zero indicates that no limit should be enforced."

So after upping the limit, I could catch the exception and make a redirection with an error message. The problem now is to find the better value for the maxSwallowSize but it's much more easier than my previous problem.

Thanks for those who were trying to help !

Comment: In the Tomcat\conf\server.xml, I had to specify the maxSwallowSize="-1". The best value for me

Comment: This opens a huge attack vector though, where clients could submit extremely large files to consume server space & memory.

Comment: @plalx Exactly. It does not solve the problem. It only makes it even worse. The solution should have been Spring Boot to be able to configure Tomcat to catch the error and forward it to controller advisers and exception handlers.